What's the proper way to setup actions using aws-load-balancer-controller
I'm using aws-load-balancer-controller 2.8.2 I'm following the official documentations. I'm deploying an Application Load balancer in AWS
my goal is to use ingress annotations to add a basic authentication token to the headers on certain paths
this is my current ingress:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.add-auth-header-blah116: |-
      {
        "Type": "forward",
        "ForwardConfig": {
          "TargetGroups": [
            {
              "ServiceName": "blah116-clusterip",
              "ServicePort": 8042
            }
          ]
        },
        "RequestHeadersConfig": {
          "RequestHeadersToAdd": [
            {
              "HeaderName": "Authorization",
              "HeaderValue": "Basic YmxhaDExNjpLVEtFP2d4dU9HT2dzNXJcaGZtYQ=="
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig":{
      "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:sa-east-1:**********:certificate/********-*********-****-************
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: uniradio-pacs
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ip-address-type: ipv4
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled=true
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-name: myapp-load-balancer
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
  creationTimestamp: "2024-09-01T19:30:04Z"
  finalizers:
    - group.ingress.k8s.aws/myapp-pacs
  generation: 9
  name: myapp-load-balancer
  namespace: myapp
  resourceVersion: "234939"
  uid: 536dc8b4-296a-4ba3-9df6-76d28fec7f4a
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: blah116.myapp.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: ssl-redirect
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
            path: /*
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          - backend:
              service:
                name: blah116-clusterip
                port:
                  name: orthanc-port
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
          - backend:
              service:
                name: add-auth-header-blah116
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
            path: /ohif
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          - backend:
              service:
                name: add-auth-header-blah116
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
            path: /studies/*/ohif-dicom-json
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          - backend:
              service:
                name: add-auth-header-blah116
                port:
                  name: use-annotation
            path: /instances/*/file
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - hostname: myapp-load-balancer-**********.sa-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Howeverm when I describe the same ingress, I get:
Rules:
  Host                     Path  Backends
  ----                     ----  --------
  blah116.myapp.com  
                           /*                           ssl-redirect:use-annotation (<error: endpoints "ssl-redirect" not found>)
                           /                            blah116-clusterip:orthanc-port (10.0.1.134:8042)
                           /ohif                        add-auth-header-blah116:use-annotation (<error: endpoints "add-auth-header-blah116" not found>)
                           /studies/*/ohif-dicom-json   add-auth-header-blah116:use-annotation (<error: endpoints "add-auth-header-blah116" not found>)
                           /instances/*/file            add-auth-header-blah116:use-annotation (<error: endpoints "add-auth-header-blah116" not found>)

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help on solving this error will be very very very appreciated :-)
I read the documention top to bottom, bottom to top looking for differences in my file and what they recommend, but couldn't find anything. The ingress deploy properly without errors, but the token is not added and I see those errors when I describe the ingress. I was expecting no errors when I describe the ingress and the token added to the the headers

You can enable ssl-redirect simply using an annotation rather then an action.
If you don't want to use the above ssl-redirect annotation, I'd suggest double checking your ssl-redirect action as the payload uses capitalized parameters vs camelCase like in the examples :)

good catch @Kris.J thanks! :-)
any idea on the other actions???

Honestly as far as I was aware, ALB doesn't allow setting/adding headers. And thats what in effect your trying to do. So unless somethings changed in that regards, would suggest adding a WAF and doing it via the WAF.
Adding a WAF isn't very expensive and has a number of benefits so its not money for nothing (i.e. adding a header).
